# Terminal command to get app switcher information?

Tags: terminal, applescript

The native app switcher orders the apps based on chronological focus. This ordering is useful to me for a script, but I'm not sure where this ordering information is stored.

Is there a way to get the app switcher list or something similar directly from terminal or applescript? Or a way to investigate where it might be?

I tried to search for this, but all of the results were about hiding apps from the switcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the man index pages I was able to find a command that gives this information:

```
lsappinfo metainfo | grep bringForwardOrder
```

This lists the apps in the same order as the app switcher when invoked, along with the app ASN, which can be useful.